I have IONIC 3 CORDOVA APP with FIREBASE PUSH and firebasex PLUGIN
I have ionic 3 cordova APP with firebase push and firebasex PLUGIN
It builds and works well fro Android, But for IOS, App gets stuck on white screen,
Whereas it works if all firebase Plugin and code is removed.
So my Question is basic.

Does IOS app build at all with FirebaseX plugin installed in Cordova app?
Does the Push token generation work with TS code in appcomponent.ts for IOS also assuming that code for Push Permission is also added before generating token ?
After ionic cordova build of app in IOS, we still need to add firebase packages in Xcode.
Also firebase app initialisation code needs to be added in appdelgate.m.

So my question is whether above setup works or for IOS the Push code and token all have to be handles only within XCode...
Anyone running this otherwise with PUSH code only from ionic and is it working?
Thanks in advance
Gopal
I have tried all sorts of things like platform removal, dependencies update, Xcode update, Change PC etc.
I am looking for confirmation that IONIC can handle PUSH code within itself or not. And a solution to my current problem, which is causing me problem of getting PUSH notifications in IOS

Contrary to your comment when this was in the Staging Ground, none of Ionic, Cordova, App, Firebase, Push, Android, or Plugin are acronyms. You don't need to "highlight" proper nouns like this. They shouldn't be capitalized, and do come across as shouting, even if you don't intend them to. Please edit your question to remove the all-caps.
